# Do I need both conditions in IIf function?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I know the syntax of the `IIf` function in SQL is

*IIf(Boolean_Expression, True_Value, False_Value)*

But I just found a SQL Code where is written

```
IIf([DATE_USER_TO_SPECIALIST] Is Not Null, Year([DATE_USER_TO_SPECIALIST]) & "." & IIf(Month([DATE_USER_TO_SPECIALIST])<=9,"0","") & Month([DATE_USER_TO_SPECIALIST])) AS DATE_USER_TO_SPECIALIST_YYYYMM
```

And it works. But how? I can't find the false value, or is the false value not required?

Comment: Why have I gotten so many negative points for my question? Can you guys help me to improve my future asked questions? I googled the problem on my own for about an hour with no success, that is why I posted it here.

Comment: I can't see any justification for downvotes on this question.  It is well-written and useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Jet-SQL` has own build-in `IIF` function which allows you to omit false part. In this case it acts like you passed `Null` value for the third argument.